# Installing APK signed with different key possible through adb install -r?

Tags: adb, apk, signature-error

Android will refuse to upgrade a package, if it is signed with a different key, making me to uninstall first (and lose user data) and re-install.

If I install the new APK via `adb install -r XYZ.apk`, I switched to the other APK and kept user data. Is that a correct workaround?

Answer (score 0):

### Rootless method:

As is mentioned above, you can uninstall an app while keeping its data with adb.

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k PACKAGE
```

> Do note that **it failed to keep data in my test case**.

Then you can install the new app with `adb install`.
Be aware that `adb uninstall` is invalid as there's no `uninstall` subcommand for adb. You must connect to a shell on your device and run `pm` from that shell. <del>However `install` is a subcommand for adb but it **does not** take any options, so if you want to run `adb install -r` you must type in `adb shell pm install -r` instead.</del>

### Root method (Recommended):

If you have root, you should never miss Xposed Framework. Get Xposed Framework and get [XInstaller](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinstaller). Navigate to "Installer Settings", scroll down and tick "Disable Signature Check". Now you can install the replacement app in any way you like.

Comment: Strange, I did `adb install -r XYZ.apk` and it worked. The `--help` says clearly `adb install [-lrtsdg] <file>`. So please write what is at least true.

Comment: The ad for Xposed, whatever it is, is really not appreciated, either.